# PHP notice undefined index only before submitting form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to do a simple value check from a form and I want to assign some variables the values entered by the user.
I have done this form :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
                <label for="raspuns1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Raspuns subpunct a</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="raspuns1" placeholder="Raspuns a"><br>
                <label for="raspuns2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Raspuns subpunct b</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="raspuns2" placeholder="Raspuns b"><br>
                <label for="raspuns3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Raspuns subpunct c</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="raspuns3" placeholder="Raspuns c"><br>
                <label for="raspuns4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Raspuns subpunct d</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="raspuns4" placeholder="Raspuns d"><br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-check"> Verifica răspunsurile</button>
    </form>
```

and this is the php code

```
<?php 
$corect1="raspunsulcorect";
$corect2="raspunsulcorect";
$corect3="raspunsulcorect";
$corect4="raspunsulcorect";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$raspuns1=$_POST['raspuns1'];
$raspuns2=$_POST['raspuns2'];
$raspuns3=$_POST['raspuns3'];
$raspuns4=$_POST['raspuns4'];
}

?>
```

The problem is that when I open the page, it shows me

```
Notice: Undefined index: raspuns1 in A:\XAMPP\htdocs\Copie\Teste\test1-geometrie.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: raspuns2 in A:\XAMPP\htdocs\Copie\Teste\test1-geometrie.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: raspuns3 in A:\XAMPP\htdocs\Copie\Teste\test1-geometrie.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: raspuns4 in A:\XAMPP\htdocs\Copie\Teste\test1-geometrie.php on line 8
```

After pressing the submit button, everything is okay, but if the page is opened the first time, this will be shown. What am I doing wrong?
That first if should not let the program check the variables

Comment: Your code and line numbers don't match...

Comment: I know, the numbers the notice is showing have no such names as raspuns1 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and add a method which checks if this is a POST request before accessing the $_POST superglobal.

Example:

```
function isPost() {
  return strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post';
}
```

In your code (assuming you have defined the above function):

```
if(isPost() && isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$raspuns1=$_POST['raspuns1'];
$raspuns2=$_POST['raspuns2'];
$raspuns3=$_POST['raspuns3'];
$raspuns4=$_POST['raspuns4'];
}
```

Also check the filter_input and filter_var functions when fetching values from the $_GET and $_POST superglobals.

Comment: I've tried the isPost function. It still shows me the same errors.

Comment: So you still see the notices even with a GET request?

Comment: Yes.
The problem is, it says Undefined index raspuns1 on line 5, but on line 5 I have no such a variable